# What is the meaning of 'SO' in Denali is SO last month?

Tags: meaning

From this [article](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/sql-2012-is-retro-%E2%80%93-what%E2%80%99s-old-is-new-again/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20sqlserverpedia%20%28SQLServerPedia%29), I guess that the name 'Denali' isn't used any longer for Microsoft SQL Server 2012, which now seems to be the official name.

But I want to know, what is the meaning of 'Denali is SO last month'.

I found these Wikipedia sites [SO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO) nor [so](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so). But I can't get the answer from them.

Comment: It's just an emphasized "so" (adverbial meaning 1 in the Wiktionary link), not an acronym or abbreviation or anything.

Comment: @Marthaª I'd say the particular nuance is not just "very", but adverbial meaning 6 in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so#Adverb), a US slang "very much" as in "that is so not true"; [OAAD](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/so) gives this in meaning 8, marked as informal and says it is used "often with a negative, before adjectives and noun phrases".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a normal "so" but capitalised for extra emphasis. The writer is saying the Denali name is redundant and oh so extremely old-fashioned.

"So last month" is usually a fashion term that demonstrates how fast the styles change, and that any stylish fashion victim wouldn't be caught dead wearing last month's designs.

Comment: That is, 'so' in this kind of context is very acceptable synonym for 'very'. Though difficult to recognize, the prescriptivist should (!) have problems with an adverb 'so' modifying a noun 'last month' (the time phrase 'last month' is acting like an adverb in a telescoped manner).

Comment: The emphasis is a parody of Californian teen dialect (Valley-speak). It's a so with an exaggerated long 'o' to mean 'very'.

Comment: @Mitch: I don't think this usage of 'so' is *very acceptable*. I can get away here with saying it's not *so acceptable*, because I'm contrasting my concept of acceptability with yours which is already "in the frame", so to speak. But (Valley-speak, etc., excepted), in formal speech/writing 'so' usually requires something which is being compared against.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: understood. modify what I said with '...in that context', which is pretty informal.

Comment: @Mitch: But you're spot-on that using either word to modify a noun is *so* [can't think of a suitable noun]!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ...is so 'on my lawn' (as in 'kids, get the hell off...')

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the SO could just as easily have been *so*.

It's for emphasis.

Like..

> This question is *so* stupid.

Just kidding.